# Подключение usb камеры к андроид приложению с использованием opencv(java/jni)

Tags: java, android, opencv, jni, web-camera

Возникла необходимость подключить внешнюю usb камеру к android приложению и вывести изображение на экран смартфона. Кто нибудь занимался схожей задачей? Работаю в Android Studio 3. Проекты(https://github.com/openxc/android-webcam, https://github.com/theicfire/simplewebcam, https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) с github вылетают с ошибками.